# AVLTree Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, avl-tree

My class is doing AVLTree's and I have an assignment I am having trouble with. I have finished implementation, but the code does not run properly. My teacher gave us a test class to check whether we did it correctly. There are several tests that my implementation doesn't pass, but I would like to focus on the first failed test for now.

This is the code for the first test.

```
           'case 1: // Test 1: add and find a few entries
            try {
            AVLTree<String, Integer> tree = new AVLTree<String, Integer>(
                    stringComp);
            String st;

            st = new String("hello");
            tree.insert(st, new Integer(0));
            st = new String("hello6");
            tree.insert(st, new Integer(1));

            if (tree.find(new String("hello")) == null
                    || tree.find(new String("hello6")) == null) {
                System.out.println("*****Test 1: Failed");
            } else
                System.out.println("Test 1: Passed");
        } catch (AVLTreeException e) {
            System.out.println("*****Test 1: Failed"); // getting this one
        }`
```

I added some print statements to check where the code was breaking and it seems that it is catching an AVLException, which I believe would mean there is something wrong either my insert or find methods.

```
public void insert(K key, V value) { //inserts at leaf node
    AVLnode<K, V> hold = TreeSearch(key, root); // find where to insert
    AVLnode<K, V> z = hold;
    DictEntry<K, V> temp = new DictEntry<K, V>(key, value); //creates the dictionary entry with key and value
    z.setEntry(temp); // sets the node being inserted to the correct key and value

    while (z != null) {
        z.resetHeight(); // incase height is changed
        if (java.lang.Math
                .abs(z.left().getHeight() - z.right().getHeight()) > 1) {
            z = triNodeRestructure(z.parent().parent(), z.parent(), z); //check if imbalanced
            z.left().resetHeight();
            z.right().resetHeight();
            z.resetHeight();
            break;
        }
        size++;
        z = z.parent();
    }

}

    public DictEntry<K, V> find(K key) {
    AVLnode<K, V> tempEntry = TreeSearch(key, root); 
    if (key.equals(tempEntry.element().key())) {
        return tempEntry.getEntry();
    } else
        return null;

}
```

I also have a private method I made to that insert and find both use

```
private AVLnode<K, V> TreeSearch(K key, AVLnode<K, V> w) { //finds the node or returns leaf node

    if (external(w)) {

        return w;
    }
    if (treeComparator.compare(key, (K) w.element().key()) < 0) {
        return TreeSearch(key, w.left());
    }

    else if (key.equals(w.element().key())) {
        return w;
    } else
        return TreeSearch(key, w.right());

}
```

Any advice or tips would be really appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Custom exceptions don't throw themselves. So where is `AVLTreeException` *thrown*? In fact, an exception will tell the exact line which it was thrown from. Just do `e.printStackTrace();`. What you're doing, `System.out.println("*****Test 1: Failed");`, is almost totally useless.

Comment: thanks for the advice, it helped me narrow my down what was wrong.